# Doctrine set Collection via join table which is now an entity

Tags: php, doctrine

I'm working on an old project where we have an entity that had a may to many collection via a join table :

```
class Company
{
    private Collection $contacts;

    public function getContacts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->contacts;
    }

    public function setContacts(Collection $contacts):void
    {
        $this->contacts = $contacts;
    }
}
```

However, over time, the join table has become an entity of its own, so now as well as a `Contact` entity,  we now have a `CompanyContact` entity. I'm refactoring the class to incorporate this change, but I'm not sure about  the `setContacts` method. Here's what I have now:

```
class Company
{
    private Collection $companyContacts;

    public function getCompanyContacts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->companyContacts;
    }

    public function setCompanyContacts(Collection $companyContacts):void
    {
        $this->companyContacts = $companyContacts;
    }

    public function getContacts(): Collection
    {
        return $this->companyContacts->map(function (CompanyContact $compayContact) {
            return $companyContact->getContact();
        });
    }

    // How should I write this method ???
    public function setContacts(Collection $contacts):void
    {
        $this->contacts = $contacts;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure  how to set this. Should I be checking through the existing `$companyContacts` and adding/removing where necessary, or creating a new Collection? We want to preserve the old methods somehow.
The first method seems to be more correct than ditching the old collection and creating a new one, since that would mean losing the additional `CompanyContact` column data, so I'm a little bit stumped here, can anyone assist? Many thanks!